# Admin submenu does not call function to load the page

Tags: oop, add-submenu-page

**Context**

I'm making a big plugin with a complex architecture. I would like in my plugin architecture split pages and menus building on admin side.

So I have these classes : `Menu.php`, `Submenu.php` and `Page.php`, `SubPage.php`

I would like, when the administrator clik on menu/submenu links, it runs a common function callback inside `Menu.php` and `Submenu.php` which load only the right page or subpage thanks `$_GET['page']`.

**Problem**

Each submenu link does not bind a subpage anymore.

All href of submenu links are in this format :

```
https://my-site.org/wp-admin/my-slug-page
```

instead of :

```
https://my-site.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-slug-page
```

**Submenu.php**

```
class SubMenu { 

    public $parent_slug;

    public $page_title;

    public $menu_title;

    public $capability;

    public $menu_slug;

    public $priority;


   public function __construct( $parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $priority = 10 ) {
       $this->parent_slug = $parent_slug;
       $this->page_title = $page_title;
       $this->menu_title = $menu_title;
       $this->capability = $capability;
       $this->menu_slug = $menu_slug;
       $this->priority = $priority;

       // Initialize the component
       add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_submenu' ), $this->priority );
   }


   public function add_submenu() {

        $page_hook = add_submenu_page(
             $this->parent_slug, 
             _x( $this->page_title, "page_title", PLUGIN_DOMAIN ), 
             _x( $this->menu_title, "menu_title", PLUGIN_DOMAIN ), 
             $this->capability, 
             $this->menu_slug, 
             array( $this, "output_rooter" ) 
        );

   }

   public function output_rooter(){
        // check $_GET['page'] value
        ...
        // Load the right SubPage class with the view
        $class = strToKamelCase( $_GET['page'] );
        new $class(); //<-- extends SubPage.php
        ... 
   }



}
```

The function `output_rooter` is never called and I have a 404 error each time I click on a submenu link.

Notice : with menu links it works correctly and all href links are perfect.

Someone has got an idea what it should be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution.

**Problem of hrefs**

> when the wordpress core did not find the function callback or it's empty for the functions `add_menu_page()` and `add_submenu_page()` the href wil be generated like this : `http(s)://my-site.org/wp-admin/my-slug-page`, otherwise the href is in this format : `http(s)://my-site.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-slug-page`

So In my case, I had to be sure the functions callback are called.

**Problem to bind the menus with page and load only the current page**

I had to call a static public function in `add_submenu_page()` which is located inside my page classes.

- Any page classes extends `Page.php`.
- Any sub pages classes extends `SubPage.php`.
- The static function to init any page/sub page is the same for all.

So I made `PageTrait.php` which is used in `Page.php` and `SubPage.php`.

This is the code :

***SubMenu.php***

```
class SubMenu { 

    public $parent_slug;

    public $page_title;

    public $menu_title;

    public $capability;

    public $menu_slug;

    protected $subpage_class; //<-- new argument used for the submenu function callbak

    public $priority;


    public function __construct( $parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $subpage_class, $priority = 10 ) {
         $this->parent_slug = $parent_slug;
         $this->page_title = $page_title;
         $this->menu_title = $menu_title;
         $this->capability = $capability;
         $this->menu_slug = $menu_slug;
         $this->subpage_class = $subpage_class;
         $this->priority = $priority;

         // Initialize the component
         add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_submenu' ), $this->priority );
    }


    public function add_submenu() {

         $page_hook = add_submenu_page(
             $this->parent_slug, 
             _x( $this->page_title, "page_title", PLUGIN_DOMAIN ), 
             _x( $this->menu_title, "menu_title", PLUGIN_DOMAIN ), 
             $this->capability, 
             $this->menu_slug, 
             array( $this->subpage_class, "init_page" ) 
         );

    }
}
```

***PageTrait.php***

```
trait PageTrait {

      public static function init_page(){
          //Code to init the right page
          //1.Get data for the constructor
          ...
          //2.Get the class path
          ...
          new $classPath( $data );
      }
}
```

***Page.php***

```
class Page {

    use PageTrait;
    ....
}
```

***SubPage.php***

```
class SubPage{

    use PageTrait;
    ....
}
```